# How to get Android to pick different layouts based on screen size

Tags: android, screen-size

I am struggling with getting my layouts to be customized and picked up by Android.
I create a test app, with these resource directories:

- layout
- layout-large
- layout-normal
- layout-small
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw720dp
- layout-w600dp
- layout-w720dp
- layout-xlarge

They basically all contain the same layout file, the only difference is that one text view simply has the content of the layout directory name:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnTest"
        android:text="Layout xxxxx" />
```

My problem is that whatever AVD I create, they all pickup the Normal layout file.
Here's what AVD's I have tested, and the output of this debug code:

```
 Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
 String sizeName = getSizeName(this);

 Log.d(TAG, String.format("screen config smallestScreenWidthDp:%d screenWidthDp:%d densityDpi:%d sizeName: %s" ,
                config.smallestScreenWidthDp, config.screenWidthDp, config.densityDpi,  sizeName)); //NON-NLS
```

- Nexus 6P, 1440x2560, 518ppi:

  - smallestScreenWidthDp:360
    screenWidthDp:360 densityDpi:640 sizeName: normal
- Galaxy S4 mini,
  4.3" 540x960, 256ppi:

  - smallestScreenWidthDp:360 screenWidthDp:360 densityDpi:240 sizeName: normal
- Wiko Goa, 3.5"
  320x480, 165 ppi:

  - smallestScreenWidthDp:320
    screenWidthDp:320 densityDpi:160 sizeName: normal

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is not an AVD issue, I get the same behaviour on physical devices; my app chooses the Normal layout on both a Nexus 6P(1440x2560, 518ppi) and a Wiko GOA(320x480, 165ppi) device.

Here's my [test project](https://github.com/MagnusJohansson/ScreenSizeTest.git) for reference.

Comment: Please try this DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

Comment: name your large, normal and small folders to sw<dp> notations also. Don't mix both naming conventions together

Comment: @M.S.P , so what should I do with that? DisplayMetrics.densityDpi is returning the same value as my other log output.

Comment: @VivekMishra, removing the sw<dp> and w<dp> folders, only leaving the -small, -normal, -large & -xlarge intact, did nothing.

Comment: small layout doesn't work now

Answer (score 0):

Either you user small, normal or large or use dp layout folders, android device will automatically fetch the correct layout as per their screen size.

Hope this will work!!

Comment: Removing the sw<dp> and w<dp> folders, only leaving the -small, -normal, -large & -xlarge intact, did nothing

Comment: will you please do the opposite of this remain sw<dp> and w<dp> layout folders and remove others.

Comment: I also designed an app for screen size 5, 7 and 10 inch respectively and for this i only use simple, sw600dp and sw720dp

Answer (score 0):

By definition

> **normal**: Screens that are of similar size to a medium-density HVGA
>   screen. The minimum layout size for a normal screen is approximately
>   320x470 dp units. Examples of such screens a WQVGA low-density, HVGA
>   medium-density, WVGA high-density.

But, since your sizes are expressed in px, we should use the following formula, for converting them to dp:

```
dp = 160 * (px/dpi)
```

Now let's consider the first one:

- Nexus 6P, 1440x2560, with densityDpi:640

In this case:

```
dp(x) = 160 * (1440/640) = 360 
dp(y) = 160 * (2560/640) = 640
```

So, this device can be considered "normal".

Considering the second one:

- Galaxy S4 mini, 4.3" 540x960 with densityDpi:240

In this case:

```
dp(x) = 160 * (540/240) = 360 
dp(y) = 160 * (960/240) = 640
```

So, this device can also be considered "normal". (it is exactly like the fist one)

This means that the actual size of the devices is basically the same for each devices you are testing.

So, if you want a larger device, maybe you should lessener the densityDpi

For example if I have a device like the S4 mini (540x960) but with densityDpi:160 will obtain:

```
dp(x) = 160 * (540/160) = 540
dp(y) = 160 * (960/160) = 960
```

That should correspond to a large or x-large device

Comment: How do I translate this into the Layout folders, I.e. how can I use different layout files for these 3 examples?

Comment: As said, I think the devices have the same size. So, I think you need to configure a proper virtual device. Lessener the resolution for one of the these three devices will increase the actual size

Comment: Well, this happens on physical devices as well. My app chooses to use the normal layout both on a Nexus 6P (1440x2560, 518ppi) and a Wiko GOA(320x480, 165ppi) so it's not an AVD issue.